# Why do bright lights glare?

Tags: visible-light

I have been trying to figure out the physical mechanism of how bright lights glare. But all I can find are ophthalmology stuff.

Yet glare affects cameras as well as eyes. It also probably can't be atmospheric, because astronomers deal with glare from bright stars obscuring planets.

So, what causes *some* light rays to disperse randomly in an otherwise clear image with a bright light source? Is it diffraction, reflection inside the camera, or something else?

Comment: Couldn't it just be the case it always glares but is too dim for you to notice?

Comment: Re, "all I can find are opthalmology stuff." Camera people talk about "lens _flare._" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare